# Flutter Razor Pay integration

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sdk, razorpay

how does this package (razorpay_flutter 1.3.4) works in flutter. In the official docs it says (This flutter plugin is a wrapper around our Android and iOS SDKs.) how exactly does this package manage to integrate in flutter. Does it install the official android or iOS SDK while runtime or in app build time

Is there a way to use Native SDK in our flutter app

Trying to understand how to use the razor pay SDK properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is very easy way to implement RazorPay in Flutter app, just follow below steps.

- add dependency in your pubspec.yaml.(https://pub.dev/packages/razorpay_flutter)
- Feel some details for payment and Add your api key, here is example of that.

  ```
    var options = {
    'key': '<YOUR_KEY_HERE>',
    'amount': 100,
    'name': 'Acme Corp.',
    'description': 'Fine T-Shirt',
    'prefill': {
    'contact': '8888888888',
    'email': 'test@razorpay.com'
    }
   };
  ```
- Now we have to open RazorPay Screen and go for pay and here is example of open razorpay screen.

  ```
   _razorpay.open(options);
  ```

I Hope this solution can be work.